# Python - import json returning module not found

Tags: python, linux, json

I am new to this whole python deal, and admit that I am half lost - don't know whether I am coming or going. So, here's the question and I hope someone can assist me.

I am running a RedHat system and by default, it has python 2.4 installed. I have a python script that gives me an error when attempting to import json.

I have checked my phpinfo and it shows that I have json version 1.2.1 (or something or other) - so why isn't Python recognizing that this json does exist? Is there a file that I need to edit to manually enter or edit where python looks for the json at, and if so, where?

I even tried installing simplejson and also python 3 - nothing has worked so far, and I have run out of hair to pull out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is not Python and the fact that your PHP version supports JSON has no effect on your Python installation. The `json` module was introduced in Python **2.6**.

<del>You could try to install [`simplejson`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/), but according to the documentation, it is only supported since Python 2.5.</del> *(should have read the whole question)*.

I would upgrade the Python version (most recent version is 2.7.2). You don't say why the installation of Python 3 didn't work, but maybe staying with the same branch (i.e. 2.7) will work out.

Comment: With 2.4 you are missing a lot of very nice features.  I also recommend upgrading if at all possible.

Comment: if I type python -v to check version - the default 2.4 comes up. If i type /opt/python3/bin/python3 -V, then i get version 3.2. But heres the part that has me confused about which version I am running - if I type python3 -V, I get command not found.

Comment: ` /opt/python3/bin` is obviously not in your `PATH`

Comment: i am not sure what you mean - but what I posted is exactly what i type in my command line - and thats the result I get - i a in the home directory - but with root access - dont know if that makes any difference

Comment: In your home dir you have some form of a .profile, or .bash_profile, etc. It defines your environment. Currently that path is not in your PATH variable so your shell doesn't know to look there to resolve `python3`

Comment: ok - looking in my Home directory - I do not see either of those two files listed - but as this is also a webserver - I have several other client accounts in here - is there a folder I should be looking in or another file name by chance.

Comment: I really appreciate yuor assistance in this - it seems that the easy install python cjson was all i needed to do - script (from the command0line) seems to be running perfectly.OK, maybe I spoke too fast - I guess I still need to get switched over to python3 - cause now I am getting 'not all arguments converted during string formatting' - and I have no idea what that means.

Comment: And if you don't find it, you can try editing `/etc/profile/.bash_profile`, like here http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm

Comment: I dont have any of that in my directories - hidden or unhidden - how can I replace my 2.4 with the 2.7 you mentioned - that seems the easiest (hopefully)

Comment: ok - for some reason - I have 2 roots - dont ask me why - I didnt create the server - I have found the .bash_profile - so how and where do i change what needs to be changed

Comment: ok - i am using the vi command and have the.bash_profile open - all I see is PATH=$PATH:HOME/bin - so would I change it to ...../opt/python3/bin

Comment: @user1257948: You would want to *add* to the path. E.g. `PATH=/opt/python3/bin:$PATH:HOME/bin`. You have to restart the console then or call `source .bash_profile` (assuming that was the file).

Comment: I am more confused now than before - I checked the python version and got a whole bunch of other stuff that wasnt there before - I hope I havent messed it up too bad - restarting servernow to see what happens

Comment: @user1257948: You don't have to restart the server... but well I guess it's too late now ;) You should find a good tutorial which explains you the basics of Linux and the command line.

Comment: i usually do not use linux servers - this will be my first and last time dealing with this - i have restarted and dont get all the mumbo jumbo when checking python version, but it still goes to the old 2.4 - not the 3 - i want the python 3 as default - but on the plus side - now the python3 -v works - but i get all the mumbo jumbo i was getting with the python -v

Comment: ok - I used the python 3 instead of just the python when installing the setup.py script - that fails - but running the normal python with the setup works fine

Comment: just curious - as with the json i was getting module did not exist, why do I also get this with sqlite3 - it works changing all references from sqlite3 to just the sqlite, but if it was written as sqlite3, I am wondering if that is my new issue. Cause when attampting to run the actual run.py - i get an error - whether I use python or python3

Answer (score 0):

python needs the **python module for json**, which is *not* the same as the php module for json.

There are some to pick from, e.g. you can use `python-cjson`, so make sure that this module is installed.

You can ask rpm about which packages are installed like this: `rpm -qa | grep json`

Comment: # rpm -qa | grep json - when inputting this - I get: 
uptrack-python-cjson-1.0.5-5.el5

Comment: what would be the correct import command to pull in this version of ppython-cjson instead

Comment: However, `json` is a standard module in Python 2.6, which means the script was written and tested for Python 2.6 or later. Even if some json module is installed and the script uses it, it seems quite probable that the script will fail in some other way because it was not written with Python 2.4 in mind.

Comment: ok - I am with you so far. So, how do I make my 3.2 install the default install instead of the 2.4

Comment: @user1257948: `import cjson as json`

Comment: @jdi - no module named cjson is what i get

Comment: @user1257948: You probably don't want to make it the default `python` command. Just add `/opt/python3/bin` to your PATH

Comment: @user1257948: " no module named cjson is what i get". Then you didnt install it.

Comment: so what does 'uptrack-python-cjson-1.0.5-5.el5' mean then if it isnt installed

Comment: It could have been installed to some area that is again not in your pythonpath. You could also try doing `easy_install python-cjson`

Comment: thank you thank you thank you thank you - import cjson works - now to test the rest of this thing and make sure everything else is working